# How do I properly use negative lookahead for this Java regex?

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I would expect this Java regex to match *all* text in between two parentheses:

```
%(.*?)\((.*?)(?!\\)\)
```

shown with comments:

```
%(.*?)      # match all text that immediately follows a '%'
\(          # match a literal left-paren
(.*?)       # match all text that immediately follows the left-paren
(?!\\)      # negative lookahead for right-paren: if not preceded by slash...
\)          # match a literal right-paren
```

but it does not (as demonstrated in this [test](http://fiddle.re/rcyg)).

For this input:

> `%foo(%bar \(%baz\)) hello world)`

I expected `%bar \(%baz\)` but saw `%bar \(%baz\` (without the escaped right-paren). I'm guessing that my usage of the negative lookahead construct is incorrect somehow. Can someone please explain the problem with my regex? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need a look around. Just use a negated character class `[^\\]` and include it in the group:

```
%(.*?)\((.*?[^\\])\)
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem. I was using negative lookahead when I actually needed negative **lookbehind**.

The regex should've been:

```
%(.*?)      # match all text that immediately follows a '%'
\(          # match a literal left-paren
(.*?)       # match all text that immediately follows the left-paren
(?<!\\)     # negative lookbehind for right-paren: if not preceded by slash...
\)          # match a literal right-paren
```

This fix is demonstrated [here](http://fiddle.re/6g8v).